# Jquery each isn't cooperating with me

Tags: jquery, each

I am building an array, and later on wish to use the keys and values it contains.

Take a look at this screenshot

[image]

Its evident the array isn't empty. But for some reason

neither

```
console.log(key)
```

nor

```
$("a[href="+key+"]").append("<span class=\"badge pull-right\">"+value+"</span>")
```

Are printing anything..

Hope you can help ^^

Comment: It says `Array[0]` at the top of your yellow box.  Even on the side, it says `results_count: Array[0]`.  Your array **is** empty.  (P.S. How did you make that appear?  How did you do that?)

Comment: what is results_count ?

Comment: is it an associate array or an array

Comment: see the difference http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jjSSK/1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jjSSK/2/

Comment: I think @ArunPJohny has the right idea.  You're probably trying to use an array (`[]`) as a "associative array".  JavaScript doesn't have those, it has objects.  You need to declare `results_count` as an object (`{}`), not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `results_count` is an array.  In JavaScript, arrays can *only* have numeric keys.  Any other property is not counted.

So if you did:

```
var results_count = [];
results_count.myKey = 6;
```

Then `results_count.length` would still be `0`, and `$.each` loops would think it's "blank".

You need to declare `results_count` as an object!  JavaScript doesn't have "associative arrays", it has objects.

Do something like this:

```
var results_count = {};
results_count.myKey = 6;
```

Then, your `$.each` would work as you expect.